# Connecting PET films electrodes to PCB

Tags: pcb, screw-terminal

I have a plastic PET film that has been sputtered with silver (electrode)

I'm trying to connect the electrode to the PCB (there are pads in the PCB).

What is the best way to achieve high conductivity without pushing the film electrodes (the thickness of silver is 50nm). I've tried to use a screw to connect the electrode to the PCB pads but the screw tightening process damages the film and the silver on top.

Any ideas?

Best,
Alam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea would be a conductive glue. Or 3D print a custom bracket that pushes the foil down.